# How to communicate using iframe between 2 angular apps ?

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I have two different angular apps. I have to open a view of 'app_2' using iframe in 'app_1'. **I also need to post some data**  from 'app_1' to 'app_2'. 
How to achieve this in angularJS?

Thanks in advance. #SOS

Comment: why you are rendering these two app in two different iframe? What you are going to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use consider using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)...

In Angular terms this would mean that one app would send messages and the other one would be listening to messages.

So on the App that sits within the iframe you can make a factory that does the following:

```
/**
 * App that sits within iframe:
 * 
 * Inject this factory into your controller and call
 * iFrame.messageParentIframe({hello: 'world'}) to send messages
 * to the parent iFrame
 */
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('iFrameMessenger', function($window) {
    return {
      messageParentIframe: function(message) {
        $window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
      }
    };
  });
```

On the parent iFrame your code should look something like this:

```
/**
 * App that is on parent iframe:
 *
 * Just using a controller for the sake of simplicity,
 * but you could also use a Factory that only receives
 * messages from iFrames and handle them according to each
 * action, etc. You can get creative here on how you want
 * to handle it.
 */
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($window) {
    $window.addEventListener('message', function() {
        // handle messages received from iframe
    });
  });
```

Comment: I wanted something like that... Thanks a lot @sergiocruz :)

Comment: Great example. I think you should call removeEventListener() from the $destroy event in AppCtrl just to make sure nothing is leaked.

Comment: What about having the other away around (parent sending a message to child iFrame), so we have a complete example of a discussion between the two?

Comment: how to call iFrame.messageParentIframe({hello: 'world'})from the app that sits within iframe:? what is iFrame here?